# How can i get response status and description when i use SftpClient.UploadFile() (on SSH.NET Library)?

Tags: c#, ssh.net

```
using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(ftpUrl, port, username, password))
{
    KeyValuePair<string, CipherInfo> temp = client.ConnectionInfo.Encryptions.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key == sftpEncryption);
    if (temp.Key == sftpEncryption)
    {
        client.ConnectionInfo.Encryptions.Clear();
        client.ConnectionInfo.Encryptions.Add(temp);
    }

    client.Connect();
    Stream stream = null; // some data to upload

    // The upload works fine but how can I see the response code (numeric code) and the response message from the server.
    client.UploadFile(stream, "my_data.bin"); 
}
```

The UploadFile method works perfectly fine.  However i'm looking to get the status code (numeric code) and response message from the FTP server after the upload goes through.  The UploadFile method returns void and the callback gives me a ulong, which I think is the size of the file that gets uploaded.  Is there any chance I can obtain the response info from the server with this library?